# How can I restore Mozilla Firefox crashed session from "sessionrestore-backups" .jsonlz4 file?

Tags: firefox, backup, data-recovery, crash

My Firefox (Quantum v.66 on Windows 10) crashed, and I accidentally clicked "Start New Session" instead of "Restore Session", which lost all of my previous tabs.

**Good news**: In my profile, in "sessionstore-backups" folder, I found a large file called previous.jsonlz4, which SEEMS like it contains all of my previous tabs and windows.

I confirmed that it's a valid file using [Session History Scrounger for Firefox](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html) tool that seemed to be the only useful resource my Googling turned up on the topic.

**Bad news**: After a couple of days of Googling, I can't seem to figure out how to restore the data from jsonlz4 file **to my browser's tabs** (basically, turn it back into crash session restore).

## How can I do that?

**What I tried:**

- Copied that jsonlz4 into "sessionrestore-backups" directory as "recovery.jsonlz4" - which seems to be the file that gets updated when FF crashes as per my experiments. This had no effect.
- Copied the JS file that Scrounger created for me into previous.js and recovery.js. No effect.
- Deleted "store.json.mozlz4" file in "crashes" subdirectory in my profile. No effect.

**Notes:**

- Note: I am **NOT** looking for random ways to get a list of URLs from the JS file that Scrounger created. I know how to do that. I want to actually import my crashed session into crash session recovery in FireFox, or into active Firefox session.
- Note: I'm aware of [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/394896/how-do-i-use-firefox-sessionstore-files-to-restore-my-crashed-session) but it asks about pre-version-57 session format circa 2012, which seems to have nothing to do with modern post-version-57 session mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

In the `sessionstore-backups` folder, identify which file you want to restore from. Just in case, the full path to get there is:

```
C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile name]\sessionstore-backups
```

Use the [Session History Scrounger](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html) for Firefox to decide which of the available files to use. I'm pretty sure you can use any of the following:

```
previous.jsonlz4
recovery.baklz4
recovery.jsonlz4
```

I can vouch that I myself recently used `recovery.baklz4` from a backup of my whole HDD when FF randomly lost all my windows and tabs after a Windows crash and FF update.

Then, go to your **main profile folder**--that means, go UP one step in the directory "tree." Paste your chosen file into this folder and rename it to `sessionstore.jsonlz4`. This should be done with FF closed, and there should already be such a file there. So do something with it--delete it, rename it, whatever--but it needs to be replaced by the file you are using to recover from. (If you do this while FF is still open, I believe it will simply overwrite it with a new file once you close it, and you will be back where you started.)

Then, open FF, and it will use the newly created `sessionstore.jsonlz4` to open all the windows and tabs.

Source:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1221836

---

However, if you just opened FF and realized your session was reset, you should NOT close it. First copy/paste all files in `sessionstore-backups` folder somewhere else and hopefully at least one of them will have your old session info.

Source:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1204253

---

I don't understand why this Jefferson person didn't simply write out these instructions on his scrounging website--would've saved everyone (including me) a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

For those (like me) who have very large *.jsonlz4 files (mine was 55MB), the Scrounger https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html actually crashes when we upload the file, so it's useless.
I created a script to extract the URLs from these large files:
https://github.com/matthieuheitz/recover-firefox-session
Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Please tell me, do you have any difficulties with such a big storage? Mine is 10.2 MB (1 window, 4500+ tabs, ~90 containers) and I've found that my firefox lags heavily when the size of sessionstore.jsonlz4 increases more than 10.3 MB

Comment: I didn't have too much problems, although maybe it depends on the size of your ram?

Comment: I honestly don't know how it happened that this file got as big as 55MB, because now when I check, on my desktop or my laptop, the files are 1MB and 1.8MB, and I have a good hundred tabs opened.

Answer (score 0):

When you accidentally start new session don't do anything in FF (don't browse Internet, etc).

- In address bar type `about:profiles` and press Enter
- Open both local and main profile directories, then backup them, just in case
- Go to `sessionrestore-backups` directory in main dir and move `previous.jsonlz4` to `recovery.jsonlz4`
- Crash FF - i.e. kill it with task manager
- Run FF again

Now you should get "restore session" tab with tabs from `previous` file.

Comment: What in the world does this mean: "move previous.jsonlz4 to recovery.jsonlz4"???? Those are files, not directories. How can you move a file to a another file? Wut?

Comment: Move is what actually happens behind the scenes when you rename files. On Linux/Unix systems, you actually use `mv` to rename files. In Windows the rename command is a synonym for moving.